# receiving form data on web api action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a mvc web application which consumes web api service. If I want send complex form data represented in `MyModel` from mvc to the webservice, should webservice have MyModel as part of the project.

This way I would have `MyModel` on both projects, mvc and web service. Is this right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion they should have different models and do the necessary mapping to avoid interdependent. In this case both projects ended up intact. This approach is called **[Data transfer object (DTO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)**.

Benefits

- You only care what you need thru mapping
- No be big effect if model in different project change
- Obviously you will not be tied up on other model outside of your domain

Disadvantages

- You will end up many models
- Expensive process

You will appreciate DTO specially if you're working in different teams working on different parts ex. One team woking on views and different team for backend. Also if your consuming external APIs. But you can apply this approach in your case.

Comment: this dto model should exist on both projects, in web api project and mvc project?

Comment: No, because if you do it will defeat the purpose